# Coloring Excel Cell based on a table condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am going through the users of a system and reviewing if they have appropriate role names. I then completed an excel table that looks abit like this:

[image: Table]

I'm trying to turn the table into a more readable format. I have made a pivot that looks like this:

[image: table 2]

But I'm not sure how to highlight the cells to reflect the 'Access Appropriate? Yes/No' column. Ideally, it should be colored yellow if the 'Access Appropriate?' = 'No'. I'm thinking of using VBA, but was wondering if there is an easier solution using formulas or pivot table?

Comment: conditional formatting using a formula to look it up from the data source?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav could you elaborate?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f  with your formula being a lookup like =vlookup(a2,data!a1:d10,4,0)="x"

Answer (score 0):

Your pivoted data isn't an actual excel pivot table, is it? I know what the `x` mean, but where do they come from?

Two possibilities come to mind if you want a flexible setup without VBA, aswell as an rather simple VBA-approach that uses an UDF.

1. Quick'n'dirty (really dirty) would be to

   - use `1/0` instead of `yes/no` (you could write that into a helper column with an `if`-function)
   - create a new pivot with `ROLE_NAME` for columns, `USER_NAME` for rows and `SUM` or `MAX` of `[Access appropriate]` for values
   - that means: instead of your `x` you will end up having `1` and `0`. Empty cells will still be empty.
   - conditional format the value-range, e.g. `If 1 then green If 0 then yellow if "" then Nothing`
2. Alternatively, you could build your output-table with formulas like `INDEX`, `MATCH` and  `VLOOKUP`-formulas.

   - An additional Key-Column with `USERNAME`&`ROLE_NAME` will be needed
   - conditional format the value-range
3. VBA: Provided your Rows are distinct a user defined function could do the following

   - read data into a `recordset` IF that hasnt been done already (meaning: declared on module-level, the first function call will fill it)
   - access the data in your recordset with a `Recordset.Filter` based on your input parameters - `USERNAME` and `ROLE_NAME`, in your case
   - output a certain `Field.Value` based on your input parameter - `Access Appropriate in your case`
   - conditional format the `TRUE/FALSE` values you get (since this can't easily be done inside an UDF)

Comment: Yes it is a pivot table. The 'x' is a replacement of all the '1' s in my table :)